# FileNotFoundException: ... Permission denied when trying to save a text file on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, storage

I have a relatively small JSON file that I use to store local user data. I read and write the file with a `Storage` class, intending to have the file saved in the app's documents directory. The class works as-intended the first time I install the app. However, if I uninstall and reinstall, the `workingFile.writeText(jsonString)` line fails with the exception `"Save failed because java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/YouKon/userdata.json: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"`.

I noticed that after the uninstall, there remain files at the location above, and it seems the app does not have access to over-write the existing files. I can delete them manually from the file browser, after which the code works again, but I don't want that to be required of the user.

The data files do not need to be in a public/visible directory.

I understand that Scoped Storage is a requirement for recent Android devices, but would like the solution to be compatible with earlier Android versions.

Below is most of the code used for the `Storage` class. The `YkUser` type is unique to my application, stores user data, and is serializable to provide a JSON string representing itself. The exception is thrown in the `saveUserToJson` method.

```kotlin
actual class Storage {
    actual companion object {
        private const val tag = "Android Storage"

        /// The URL where the user data file will be stored
        private val documentsUrl: File
            get() = File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS
                ),
                "YouKon"
            )

        /// The working file, which will be imported on startup, and saved any time the user modifies the data
        private val workingFile: File
            get() = File("${documentsUrl.absolutePath}/userdata.json")

        actual fun saveUserToJson(user: YkUser) {
            val jsonString = user.asJsonString()
            try {
                if (!workingFile.exists()) {
                    // If the file doesn't exist, try creating it along with the necessary directories
                    workingFile.parentFile?.mkdirs()
                    workingFile.createNewFile()
                }
                workingFile.writeText(jsonString)
                Log.d(tag, "Save succeeded to $workingFile")
            } catch(exception: Exception) {
                Log.d(tag,"Save failed because $exception")
                exception.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The data files do not need to be in a public/visible directory.

Then do not put them in a public/visible directory. Instead, write them to the directory returned by `getFilesDir()` on `Context`. You have full read-write access to that location and do not need any permissions. This works back to Android 1.0.

Comment: Any recommendation for how to get `Context` inside the `Storage` class? This is in a Kotlin Multiplatform app, hence the `actual` declarations. This is the Android implementation, however, the ViewModel that calls this method is not always going to be Android, and so `Context` will not always be available. So, I would like to have the context encapsulated in the class itself.

Comment: @MobileMultibodyDynamics: Off the cuff, use dependency inversion (e.g., Koin) to inject a repository that has your `Context` or inject the `Context` itself.